# Recursivity in methods, Algorithm and NSValue issue

Tags: objective-c, algorithm

```
-(BOOL)isInArray:(CGPoint)point{
    if ([valid count]==0) {
        return NO;
    }

    for (NSValue *value in valid) {
        CGPoint er=[value CGPointValue];

        if( CGPointEqualToPoint(point,er)) return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}



-(void)check:(CGPoint)next{

if (!next.y==0) {

    int ics=(int) next.x;
    int igrec=(int)next.y;

    if (mat[ics][igrec]==mat[ics-1][igrec]){

        if (![self isInArray:next]) {
            [valid addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:next]];
            NSLog(@"valid y!=0 : %@",valid);

            [self check:CGPointMake(ics-1, igrec)];
        }
    }
}
```

}

y are columns , x are rows , mat is a C matrix

what i'm trying to do here is this:i get a point, `next`, in a matrix,`mat` (i'll use struct but for the scope of testing i use CGPoint..it's basicaly the same thing), and for that point i check if it's on the first row and if it's not i check if the value is equal to the value of the row above .If it is, i add the coord of the point into an array and move to the value above (recursively). I have ifs for left,right, and below too...but the idea is the same.

My issues:

- For some reason it doesn't work as it should, even with a mat full of 1 values
- The NSMutableArray i use to store the points is always null (note that the NSLog gets  called so it should've added an object already)

  - Does recursivity work with methods?
  - If you have a better idea how to do this...i'm listening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "valid" array is nil because you haven't allocated it. (You can send an addObject: message, or any message, to a nil pointer--it just doesn't do anything.) Make sure you've got

```
valid = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

somewhere before you're calling this code.

Also, "!next.y==0" is questionable. It might turn out to be identical to "next.y != 0" even if ! has a higher precedence that ==, but I wouldn't guarantee it. That's all I spot for now, without really grokking what this code is trying to do..

---

Oh, another quick note: Instead of writing your own isInArray, just use NSArray's containsObject:. The inner part of the check method (second indent) is then

```
NSValue* pointVal = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:next];

if ( ![valid containsObject:pointVal] )
{
    [valid addObject:next];
    [self check:CGPointMake(ics-1, igrec)];
}
```

Or, if you don't care about the order of the points in the valid array you could use an NSMutableSet instead and not worry about checking if the point is already in the collection.

And yes, recursion in methods is fine. They're really the same as C functions, just with a couple hidden arguments (the self pointer and the method name) and called through a dispatch function.

Comment: well..i'm now using NSSet, moved some things around...it works..but it doesnt work as it should..i'll try to fix it but if it doesnt work i'll put the code here ...maybe you can help me some more :)

Comment: so i concluded it doesn't call `[self check:CGPointMake(ics-1,igrec)];` ...any ideas?    (or if it does...it doesn't work recursively )

Comment: it seemed it was a mistake on my part..a small one..but now it works perfectly..thank you

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the check: call was dependent on whether the point was already in the valid list. So if you use a set instead you'll still need the containsObject: call, but that's much faster on a set than an array if you've got lots of points in it. Just being pedantic here. :)